# rs.initiate method not working on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

I'm running MongoDB 3.2.15 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I can't execute `rs.initiate();`. It returns the following error

```
{
  "ok" : 0,
  "errmsg" : "assertion src/mongo/db/repl/replset_commands.cpp:275",
  "code" : 8
}
```

opened mongo with the following arguments

```
mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf --replSet rs0
```

Configuration file :

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

The log file :

```
2017-07-26T08:25:38.400+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2017-07-26T08:25:42.186+0000 I COMMAND  [conn1] initiate : no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set
2017-07-26T08:25:42.186+0000 I -        [conn1] Assertion failure h != "localhost" src/mongo/db/repl/replset_commands.cpp 275
```

Comment: Looks like the path to your conf file is wrong?

Comment: @Eric i double checked and the path is correct. There are lines in the log file that shows that I got the right configuration loaded.

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Answer (score 4):

Try this (success for me):

```
mongo
> config = {_id:"rs0", members:[ {_id:0, host:"127.0.0.1:27017"}]}
{
    "_id" : "rs0",
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "127.0.0.1:27017"
        }
    ]
}
> rs.initiate(config)
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

Reference: http://blog.csdn.net/Aegeaner/article/details/56277129